# Long-call asynchronous data delivery for Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have a rails app that does some user-driven/filtered data representation over a large dataset. So we're calculating things on the fly and it takes longer than the 15s Unicorn gives us!

What's the best option here? I was thinking of using a pub/sub model (like a Node/Faye setup) to allow the rails app to send data that the browser could then render.

I guess another option is to try to pre-generate the data, but as we have a lot of clients and very few would be looking at the data it seems like we'd be wasting a lot of time on preparing data that would never be used.

Comment: Why not dedicating a worker on it so that it is threaded and user can check a specific page to see if done. Or even sending an email with link when ready. This is typically something to give to Sidekiq.

Comment: Also what you can do, to simulate the on the fly process: trigger an Ajax periodic call to check if your background job is done while you display a loading icon on the page. One drawback: if your background job queue is busy with other requests, it may take a longer time than normal (then the visitor may think something broke, as it is actually not on the fly)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with pre-generating the data.

If you're concerned about needless number crunching and want to do it on-demand, you could kick off a background job to process the data, and poll periodically to see if the background generation is done or not.

If you're looking for a library to do this for you:

Alternatively, if you're using ActionCable already, [`get_schwifty`](https://github.com/danielwestendorf/get_schwifty) was built for this very purpose (shameless plug, I'm the author).

[`render_async`](https://github.com/renderedtext/render_async) is another option if you're not using ActionCable, however, I beleive it still does the processing in a Unicorn process instead of a background job.

Comment: Thanks! So low tech with the polling! I like it. I'm on Rails 4.2 (should have put that in the question) and moving to Rails 5 seems to be going to happen later. This issue with the long data render is urgent.

Comment: Thanks again for the ideas. What I ended up doing is creating a "token", dropping a job into delayed job then storing the result into cache with the token as the key when its done. The webpage (which got the token back in the response) then calls an action method to see if the token exists and has data. Works a treat.